# OpenCV:split HSV image and scan through H channel

Tags: opencv

I meet a problem when I want to scan through H channel and print its pixel values after splitting a HSV image.**The problem is that the outputs are not numbers but messy codes.**

Following is my code(**using Opencv**):

```
Mat hsv;
cvtColor(saveImage,hsv,CV_BGR2HSV);// convert BRG to HSV
vector<cv::Mat> v_channel;
split(hsv,v_channel);          //split into three channels
if (v_channel[0].data==0)      //channel[0] is Hue
{
    cout<<"Error getting the Hue***********"<<endl;
}

for (int i=0;i<hue.rows;i++)     //scan through Hue 
{
    for (int j=0;j<hue.cols;j++)
    {
        cout<<v_channel[0].at<uchar>(i,j)<<endl;
    }
}
```

Hope anyone could help . Thanks very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data is stored as bytes, ie chars, the output is interpreting the chars as, well, chars and trying to print the symbol. Simply tell it they are integers

`cout<< (int) v_channel[0].at<uchar>(i,j)<<endl;`

Comment: Well, that works !Thank you much very ! It seems that i still have a long way to go in the programming way~