# Convert from Vec3b to Mat3b

Tags: opencv, image-processing, hsv

I am using BGR to HSV conversion of image using OpenCV. Since I am new to this field and software, I may sound incorrect so please let me know if I am wrong.

Now, in my school project i want to work with HSV image, which is easily converted using

```
cvtColor(src, dst, CV_BGR2HSV);
```

I suppose, that imread() function reads image in a uchar format which is 8bit unsigned image (i suppose). In that case imshow() is also uchar.

But to work with HSV image, I am not sure but I feel i need to convert use Mat3b perhaps for the distinctive H, S and V channels of the image.

Incase if I am wrong, that I want to work with H channel of the HSV image only so how can i print, or modify this channel information.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can use cv::split to devide the HSV to 3 one-channel Mat. I think this topic [OpenCV:split HSV image and scan through H channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724003/opencvsplit-hsv-image-and-scan-through-h-channel) may solve your problem.

Comment: thanks but let me ask u, in HSV, H is between 0-360, S & V is between 0 -100. However when i print the values its seems to exceed the 0-100 range. For example {118, 26, 248}. Is there any problem in my conversion

Comment: Different lib have different HSV value range, I think you can check here [Choosing correct HSV values for OpenCV thresholding with InRangeS][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948589/choosing-correct-hsv-values-for-opencv-thresholding-with-inranges